# How to restore from a scrambled screen?

Tags: shell, terminal, tty

My screen is scrambled while reading some unexpected chars,

[image]

It happens in a local tty, so logging out won't help.

Any ideas? Hopefully I don't have to reboot

Comment: If `Ctrl-l` or `reset` doesn't work, you could try `setfont`...

Comment: @jasonwryan Oh I thought that was a encoding problem, going to try that soon

Comment: @jasonwryan `setfont` doesn't work, `reset` did the job

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either type `reset` at the prompt, or if it's a graphical terminal it probably has a menu option to reset the terminal. If it's a virtual terminal then restarting the `getty` process providing the terminal will accomplish the same thing.

What happens is the terminal got stuck in "alternate character set". So it just needs to be reset to normal state.

Comment: Just confirmed `reset` works in a terminal emulator as well ;-P